# Django on migrate says relation does not exists

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

Hello this is not a common problem even thought this error is everywhere.

I am using Django 2.2 + drf + postgresql

## My problem.

After adding a new model. I have added a model serialzer which has a Charfield with choices.

so my serializer looks something like that.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   my_choice_field = serializers.ChoiceField(choices = [obj.code for obj in Object.objects.all()])
```

When i run `./manage.py migrate` it executes the serializer first and raises an error which says that the relation does not exists.

## What I have tried

reorder INSTALLED_APPS

run `./manage.py migrate my_app`

## My goal

To run migrations before loading the serializer or make a check if the model exists, if not leave empty list of choices.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: FWIW, reading *all records* from the database upon start up is what's wrong here, not the missing relation. You need to populate those choices at a different time and place. Focus your question on that.

Comment: The duplicate question is about a form instead of a serializer, but the same approach should work here. Define a callable `def get_codes(): return [obj.code for obj in Object.objects.all()]`. Then in your serializer do `my_choice_field = serializer.CharField(choices-get_codes)`.

Comment: Did you run makemigrations?